# Implementation of multiple objects in thread

Tags: php, multithreading, oop, pthreads

I want to use multiple object in thread, but resources id of objects are the same when i used multi thread.(i.e all of them resource id #2).

```
class Async extends Thread
{
    public function run()
    {
        $obj = new socket($newValue); // resources id are the same  . for example #2
    }
}
```

For this reason, i want to implement instance of class from out of thread class and pass object by parameter of thread constructor, but this is not working.
I want to implement something like the following codes:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    $obj = new socket($i);
    $example[$i] = new Async($obj);
    $example[$i]->start();
}
```

But the object is not detected within the run method.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Try to clarify it. Also, resource numbers are not connected in any way and threads are not connected to each other so it doesn't matter if you get the same resource_id in **different** threads.

Comment: I noticed. tnx a lot.